# Win32API DefWindowProc not processing line feed and carriage return

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm upgrading a program that uses MFC from VS6 to VS2010 and DefWindowProc is partially working, it displays any character with the exception of carriage return and line feed on the CRichEditBox.

Anyone have any ideas? Is there a better function to call ? I did not write this code btw.

DefWindowProc( WM_CHAR, (WPARAM) 0x0D, 0); -- Does nothing

DefWindowProc( WM_CHAR, (WPARAM) 'b' , 0); -- Works

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Forgot to add -- it worked in VS6

Comment: Silly question, but is the control created with the `ES_MULTILINE` style?

Comment: I'll check that and let you know.

Comment: Can't find where the create window is called yet

Comment: Why are you using `DefWindowProc()` to process hard-coded characters? Why not just assign the desired characters directly to the `CRichEditBox`?

Comment: Did you try `'\n'` for line feed and `'\r'` for carriage return?

Comment: The control will definitely need both a CR and a LF to wrap to the next line.

Comment: Yeah, tried '\r' and '\n', not appearing. Reading the hex file and nothing.